# Laravel 5.5: Move data from home page to register

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have an index.blade.php file (home page of website) where a user can fill out some details (name and email) and what I'm looking to do is pass that data on to the register.blade.php file and populate the form there with the previous inputs. I've read quite a few posts on here regarding the old() function but I can't get that to work exactly.

index.blade.php

```
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="form1" class="form-control validate">
                                <label for="form1">Name</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" name="email" id="form2" class="form-control validate">
                                <label for="form2">E-Mail</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <a href="{{ route('register') }}">
                                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Register</button>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

register.blade.php is the default file generated with php artisan make:auth command, nothing changed there

Comment: if i get your point correctly you want to have old data was input in fields right? if so, just use `value=&amp;amp;quot;{{old(&#39;email&#39;)}}` in your email input. same goes for other fields.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, only getting empty results

Comment: make your id and name same, `name="email"` `id="email"`

Answer (score 2):

Add the following method to your controller

```
   public function register(Request $request){
        return view('register', ['name' = $equest->name, 'email' => $request->email]);
    }
```

**register.blade.php**

```
{{ $name}}
{{ $email }}
```

the above are used to display values

Comment: This is the right answer, however if you have different index and register views, you need to pass entered data from form in index, to register route, handled by a method like in @nikhil example (name register would be more adequate then)

Comment: Using yours and Barts comments I tried to implement this but at first I got an error with the action not being defined. So, I added it into my routes and now I'm being told RegisterController doesn't exist. I can't even run the route:list command

Comment: php artisan make: controller RegisterController

Answer (score 0):

You can create cookies ?

create a cookie on your index.blade.php

```
document.cookie = "name=John Doe; email=john@doe.com";
```

then use it in register.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

you can store them in session like this

```
session(['name' => 'user name here']);
```

and then access them with

```
$name = session('name');
```